# In F# what are these collection-looking things?

Tags: f#

In F# there are many different collection-looking syntaxes that compile into something. What are they all, and what do they mean?

```
let s1 = [a, b, c, d]
let s2 = [a; b; c; d]
let s3 = (a, b, c, d)
let s4 = (a, b, c, d)
let s5 = [|a, b, c, d|]
let s6 = [|a; b; c; d|]
let s7 = a, b, c, d
let s8 = { aa = 3; bb = 4 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[a, b, c, d]` is a list with a single 4-tuple as element.

`[a; b; c; d]` is a four-element list.

`(a, b, c, d)` is a 4-tuple.

`[|a, b, c, d|]` is an array with a single 4-tuple as element.

`[|a; b; c; d|]` is a four-element array.

`a, b, c, d` is a 4-tuple.

`{ aa = 3; bb = 4 }` is a value of a record type with two fields `aa` and `bb`.

Answer (score 4):

Answer provided by райтфолд gives you answer, I'll try give you a way to get answer by yourself next time you have a question like this.

The easiest way is to use [F# interactive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233175.aspx) (you can start it from Visual Studio from View -> Other Windows -> F# Interactive). Just type F# code, add double semicolon `;;` and hit ENTER. To make your declarations work you have to declare `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` first. Let's make them all integers:

```
> let a = 1
let b = 2
let c = 3
let d = 4
;;

val a : int = 1
val b : int = 2
val c : int = 3
val d : int = 4
```

Now you can try your declarations:

```
> let s1 = [a, b, c, d];;

val s1 : (int * int * int * int) list = [(1, 2, 3, 4)]
```

F# Interactive prints back the type of expression that was evaluated. In that case it's `(int * int * int * int) list`. How to read that? `*` is used to divide elements of a [**tuple type**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233200.aspx), so `(int * int * int * int)` means a tuple with four elements, all types as `int`. Following `list` means [**a list**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233224.aspx) of those. So `(int * int * int * int) list` is a list of tuples with four `int`-typed elements each.

```
> let s2 = [a; b; c; d];;

val s2 : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4]
```

Similar concept, this time it's a `list` of `int` elements.

```
> let s3 = (a, b, c, d);;

val s3 : int * int * int * int = (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

This one was already explained above: `int * int * int * int` is a four element tuple with all elements typed as `int`.

```
> let s5 = [|a, b, c, d|]
let s6 = [|a; b; c; d|];;

val s5 : (int * int * int * int) [] = [|(1, 2, 3, 4)|]
val s6 : int [] = [|1; 2; 3; 4|]
```

These are very similar to `s1` and `s2`, but instead of `list` element type is followed by `[]` - that means it's [**an array**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233214.aspx). `s5` is an array of `(int * int * int * int)` elements and `s6` is an array of `int` elements.

```
> let s7 = a, b, c, d;;

val s7 : int * int * int * int = (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Same as `s3`.

```
> let s8 = { aa = 3; bb = 4 };;

  let s8 = { aa = 3; bb = 4 };;
  -----------^^

stdin(18,12): error FS0039: The record label 'aa' is not defined
```

This one is tricky. To make it work you have to declare [**record type**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233184.aspx) first:

```
> type myRecordType = { aa: int; bb: int };;

type myRecordType =
  {aa: int;
   bb: int;}
```

with that it works and prints that `s8` is an instance of `myRecordType`:

```
> let s8 = { aa = 3; bb = 4 };;

val s8 : myRecordType = {aa = 3;
                         bb = 4;}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's an interesting answer, once I take the time to read it. :)

Answer (score 2):

`let s1 = [a, b, c, d]`
Equivalent to `[(a, b, c, d)]`: a list containing one quadruple (**[tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233200.aspx)** of 4 elements).

`let s2 = [a; b; c; d]`
A **[list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233224.aspx)** with 4 elements.

`let s3 = (a, b, c, d)`
A quadruple.

`let s4 = (a, b, c, d)`
The same quadruple.

`let s5 = [|a, b, c, d|]`
Equivalent to `[|(a, b, c, d)|]`: an **[array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233214.aspx)** containing one quadruple.

`let s6 = [|a; b; c; d|]`
An array with 4 elements.

`let s7 = a, b, c, d`
A quadruple (can omit brackets in this case and when there is no ambiguity).

`let s8 = { aa = 3; bb = 4 }`
A **[record](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233184.aspx)** definition.